# Using a submit button dependent on another one being submitted first

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm relatively new to PHP, I'm back in school after working in an unrelated field for a number of years.  I'm working on an outside project for my Dad and have run into what appears on the surface to be an easy-to-solve issue that I can't seem to resolve.

On the page in question it displays a list of players in a league and their score.  The form below it has a text box allowing you to enter a name and three buttons; one to add the name as a player (with a default score of 0), delete that player from the list of players, and a third to adjust the score for that player.  I got the first two ("add" and "delete") to work as I'd like, however where I'm running into a problem is with the score adjustment one.

If you click the "adjust score" button it displays a new text box to enter the score along with another button to actually submit it.  The problem is *nothing* happens when you press the new button to adjust the score, at this point I've just got a test "echo" statement in there that should be displaying on submission, but that's not happening.  Below is the code in question.  Any thoughts on how I can fix?  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<html>
<head>
    <LINK REL="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/footballTest.css" />
    <title>VFW Football testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $dbConnect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
        $dbName = "vfwleaguetest";
        $getPlayers = "SELECT * FROM `players`";
        if(!$dbConnect)
        {
            echo "<p>Connection failed</p>";
        }   
        if(mysql_select_db($dbName, $dbConnect) === false)
        {
            echo "<p>Could not select the database ".$dbName ."<br/>".mysql_error($dbConnect)." </p>";
        }
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name=@$_POST['nameAdd'];
            $playerAdd = "INSERT INTO `vfwleaguetest`.`players` (`playerName`, `seasonTotal`) VALUES ('".$name."', '0')";
            if(mysql_query($playerAdd, $dbConnect) === false)
            {
                echo "<p>Error adding player to database: ".mysql_error($dbConnect)."</p>";
            }
        }
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        if(isset($_POST['delete']))
        {
            $name= @$_POST['nameAdd'];
            $playerDelete = "DELETE FROM `vfwleaguetest`.`players` WHERE `players`.`playerName` = '".$name."'";
            if(mysql_query($playerDelete, $dbConnect) ===false)
            {
                echo "<p>Error deleting player to database: ".mysql_error($dbConnect)."</p>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo $name." successfully removed from player list";
            }
        }
        if(isset($_POST['adjust']))
        {
            ?>
            <br/>
            <input type='text' name='scoreAdjust' size=5 />&nbsp;
            <input type='submit' name='fixScore' value='new season total for <?php echo $_POST['nameAdd'];?>' />
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['fixScore'])) //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM SEEMS TO LIE
            {
                echo "after fixScore click";
                //add sql below
            }
        }   
    ?>
    <form name="players" action="" method="post">
    <?php
        $playerList = mysql_query($getPlayers, $dbConnect);
        echo "<table><th><tr>";
        echo "<td>Player name</td><td>Season total</td></tr></th>";
        while(($row = mysql_fetch_row($playerList)) != false)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?>
    Manage players&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nameAdd" />&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="adjust" value="adjust score" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have now is **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.  Also, use `htmlspecialchars()` around any variable data you are outputting to HTML, so that certain data doesn't break your page, and so that you are not so vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: Another friendly tip: use of the `mysql` extension [is discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). Look at using `mysqli` or `PDO` as Brad pointed out.

Comment: Also, [`Mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) should be used (it stands for MySQL Improved), and [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to sanitize database queries. Otherwise, as @Brad says, your website `is wide open to SQL injection, and you *will be hacked*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is score adjust inputs are out of the form:

```
<input type="text" size="5" name="scoreAdjust">
<input type="submit" value="new season total for aaa" name="fixScore">
```

you need:

```
<form method="post" action=''>
  <input type="text" size="5" name="scoreAdjust">
  <input type="submit" value="new season total for aaa" name="fixScore">
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need `action=''`. If omitted, the page will submit to itself.

Comment: Thanks Alireza, Shaquin, Brad, and Deefour!  I'd have sworn I tried a version of this where everything necessary WAS in the form, but I must have missed something somewhere.  After some minor tinkering it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input>` element for `scoreAdjust` needs to be within the `<form>` element that is being submitted.

Comment: Thanks Brad, Shaquin and Deefour!  I appreciate your additional concern about SQL injection, and I know that yeah, in it's current state it is indeed asking to be hacked.  Right now I'm just trying to get the functionality down, once I have that I'll go back and implement the safeguards as suggested.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
            <br/>
            <form method="post">
                <input type='text' name='scoreAdjust' size=5 />&nbsp;
                <input type='submit' name='fixScore' value='new season total for <?php echo $_POST['nameAdd'];?>' />
            </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['fixScore'])) //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM SEEMS TO LIE
            {
                echo "after fixScore click";
                //add sql below
            }
```

For a field to be submitted into `$_POST`, it needs to be inside a `form`.